# Representing subtype relationship with <: and <:< in Scala

Tags: scala

Generally, I use <: to represent a subtype relationship like A <: B, either as part of type parameter or as a type member. When going through some stuff, I came across this "<:<" representation. Found it in Predef.scala and surprisingly, it is defined as an abstract class.
Doc says that:

> An instance of `A <:< B` witnesses that `A` is a subtype of `B`. Requiring an implicit argument of the type `A <:< B` encodes the generalized constraint `A <: B`.

Could some one please clarify what exactly is the difference between the two, given the fact that both represents the same "subtype" relationship (AFAIK). Also, please suggest their correct usage (I mean, where <:< is preferred over <:) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[A <: B]` declares a type parameter, `A`, with a known property/restriction: it must be type `B` (an existing type) or a sub-type thereof.

```
class A  // A and B are unrelated
class B

// these both compile
def f1[A <: B]() = ???  // A is the type parameter, not a reference to class A
def f2[B <: A]() = ???  // B is the type parameter, not a reference to class B
```

`[A <:< B]` is used to test existing types.

```
class B
class A extends B

// A and B must already exist and have this relationship or this won't compile
implicitly[A <:< B]
```

Comment: do you know any difference when we use them in the following context: `def test1[A <: B, B] ()` and `def test2[A, B] (implicit w: A <:< B) ` ? it looks pretty similar from compiler perspective

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko; Yes, as far as I can tell, the results are the same. `test2` does go through the effort of looking up the implicit and placing it in the local name-space, `w`. So, in addition to being more verbose, it might also be a bit less efficient.

Comment: I would like to complement this answer with a link to [this post](https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html?m=1) which gives a very detailed explanation of why `<:<` exists and when is useful. TL;DR; Type constraints, sometimes, are unable to prove complex restrictions - leading to compile errors, or wrong inferred types. On those cases `<:<` is usually capable of producing the desired result. The trick is that for `<:<` the type information of the parameters was already solved, on the opposite, for `<:` the type information of the parameters is being solved.